# How to get max of composite data in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, nested, max, composite

```
SELECT "Name""Month","Year","Value" 
from Table
WHERE 
    "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%'
AND "Year" = 
    (SELECT MAX("Year") FROM Table where "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%')
AND "Month"= 
    (SELECT MAX("Month") FROM Table 
     where 
        "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%' 
    AND "Year"= (SELECT MAX("Year") FROM Table where "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%'))
```

Table -->

```
Name  | Year | Month | Value
-----------------------------
JERRY   2012    9        100           
JERRY   2012    9        120         
JERRY   2012    9        130           
JERRY   2012    8         20        
JERRY   2011    12        50
```

So i want the first three rows as output. As for the latest month for the latest year i need all the values. 
Can someone suggest a better cleaner query?

Comment: I don't understand your output requirements. Also -- the sample data should presumably contain another person's data rather than just JERRY's?

Comment: Can you provide data in a DML like this:

Comment: CRATE TABLE #sample (
   [Name] VARCHAR(255)
 , [Year] INT
 , [Month] INT
 , [Value] INT
 )
 
INSERT #sample ([Name], [Year], [Month], [Value])
VALUES ('JERRY', 2012, 9, 100)           
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 9, 120)
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 9, 130)
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 8, 20)
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 12, 50)

SELECT * FROM @sample'code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there are other people in the table then you probably want to use a ranking function: Something like:

```
DECLARE @sample TABLE (
      [Name] VARCHAR(255)
    , [Year] INT
    , [Month] INT
    , [Value] INT
    )

INSERT @sample ([Name], [Year], [Month], [Value])
VALUES ('JERRY', 2012, 9, 100)           
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 9, 120)
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 9, 130)
     , ('JERRY', 2012, 8, 20)
     , ('JERRY', 2011, 12, 50)
     , ('FRED', 2011, 12, 50)
     , ('FRED', 2011, 12, 120)
     , ('FRED', 2011, 7, 150)

SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT *
         , RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY [Name] ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC) AS [rnk]
    FROM @sample
    )
    AS samp
WHERE
    samp.[rnk] = 1
```

Which gives results:

```
Name                      Year        Month       Value       rnk
------------------------- ----------- ----------- ----------- ------
FRED                      2011        12          50          1
FRED                      2011        12          120         1
JERRY                     2012        9           100         1
JERRY                     2012        9           120         1
JERRY                     2012        9           130         1
```

Comment: I like your answer but `ORDER BY [Year] * 100 + [Month] DESC` really? Why not `ORDER BY [Year] DESC, [Month] DESC` ?

Comment: @ypercube, as per OP "So i want the first three rows as output. As for the latest month for the latest year i need all the values. "

Comment: @Niladri: This gives the first rows (latest year,latest month) **per Name**. If the `WHERE "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%'` is included in the internal subquery, the result is exactly what the OP wants.

Comment: The filtering is done by the `RANK()` function and the `WHERE samp.[rnk] = 1`

Comment: Yes, I got your point.. you are right..in that case Partition By Name Order By [Year] desc, [Month] Desc is enough

Answer (score 2):

```
DECLARE @t Table(Name Varchar(30),[Year] Int, [Month] Int,Value Int)
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY' ,  2012,    9,        100 )
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY',   2012,    9 ,       120)         
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY' ,  2012,    9 ,       130)           
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY',   2012 ,   8 ,        20)        
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY',   2011,    12 ,       50) 


Declare @LatestYr Int 
Declare @LatestMonth Int

Select @LatestYr= Max([Year])From @t
Select @LatestMonth = Max([Month]) From @t Where [Year] = @LatestYr

Select * From @t
Where ([Year] = @LatestYr And [Month] = @LatestMonth)
```

**Result**

[image]

The above query will work just for a single user. And will fail for multiple users, or in case of ties. For example, consider the below scenario

[image]

In this case, the needed output will be

[image]

So for handling such a situation, I am proposing the below solutions

**Solution 1**

```
Select t.* 
From @t t
Join
(
    Select x.Name,x.Max_Year,y.Max_Month
    From
        (   SELECT Name,Max_Year = Max([Year])
            From @t
            Group By Name
        )x
    Join
        (   SELECT Name,[Year],Max_Month= Max([Month])
            From @t
            Group By Name,[Year]
        )y On x.Name = y.Name And x.Max_Year = y.[Year]
)x
On t.Name = x.Name 
And t.[Year] = x.Max_Year 
And t.[Month] = x.Max_Month
```

OR

**Solution 2 (Sql Server 2005+)**

```
Select Name,[Year],[Month],Value
From
(
    Select *,Rn = Rank() Over(Partition By Name Order By [Year] desc, [Month] Desc) 
    From @t
)X Where X.Rn =1
```

**Solution 3 (Sql Server 2005+)**

```
Select Name,[Year],[Month],Value
From
(
    Select *,Rn = Dense_Rank() Over(Partition By Name Order By [Year] desc, [Month] Desc) 
    From @t
)X Where X.Rn =1
```

The ddl is as under

```
DECLARE @t Table(Name Varchar(30),[Year] Int, [Month] Int,Value Int)
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY' ,  2012,    9,        100 )
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY',   2012,    9 ,       120)         
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY' ,  2012,    9 ,       130)           
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY',   2012 ,   8 ,        20)        
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY',   2011,    12 ,       50) 
Insert Into @t Values('FERRY' ,  2010,    9,        100 )
Insert Into @t Values('FERRY',   2010,    9 ,       120) 
Insert Into @t Values('FERRY',   2010,    8 ,       120) 
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY1' ,  2012,    9,        100 )
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY1',   2012,    9 ,       120)         
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY1' ,  2012,    9 ,       130)           
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY1',   2012 ,   8 ,        20)        
Insert Into @t Values('JERRY1',   2011,    12 ,       50)
```

Hope this may help. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
select * from @t where
[Year] = (select max([year]) from @t) and 
[Month] = (select max([Month]) from @t where [Year]=(select max([year]) from @t))
```

Comment: @NiladriBiswas -- di dyou check the latest query?

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from    your_table
where   "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%' 
and     year*100+month 

in(
    select top 1 year*100+month 
    from your_table
    where 
    "Name" LIKE '%JERRY%' 
    order by cast(year*100+month as int) desc)
```

## [CLICK for demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d0a03/7)